# empty set and whole set belongs in every semi algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

My attempt:

Let $A$ then $A^c=\cup_{n=i}^{n}A_i$, where $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are disjoint sets in $R$.

Since $A , A_i\in R$ and $R$ is closed under finite intersection then $A\cap A_i\in R$.

Hence $\phi=A\cap A^c=\cup_{n=i}^{n} (A\cap A_i)$, where $A\cap A_i$ are disjoint sets in $R$.

Since $\phi$ is a finite union of disjoint sets in $R$, then $\phi^c=\Omega\in R$.

But now how to prove that $\phi\in R$?

Comment: $\emptyset = A - A$ for any $A \in R$. So if $R$ is non-empty...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, but how does that prove that $\phi$ or $\Omega$ in $R$.?

Comment: What's your definition of semi-algebra?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, non-empty, closed under finite intersection and if $A\in F$ then $A^c$ equal to finite union of disjoint sets in $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a member of the semi-algebra $R \neq \emptyset$. Then $A^\complement$ is a disjoint union of some $B_1, \ldots, B_n$ for some finite $n$ and all $B_i \in R$. If $n=1$, then $A^\complement$ is in $R$ so $A \cap A^\complement = \emptyset$ is in $R$ too. If $ n \ge 2$ then $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset \in R$ as well, by closedness under finite intersections.

So $\Omega = \emptyset^\complement$ is also a finite disjoint union of sets $C_i \in R$ for $i=1,\ldots, m \in \Bbb N$. Again if $m=1$ we're done and $\Omega \in R$. If $m\ge 1$ I don't see how to make progress towards $\Omega \in R$. Applying intersections to the $C_i$ is pointless and the complement property yields nothing new for them either.

And $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}\}$ is a semi-algebra on $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ without $\Omega$ in it...

Comment: Do you mean "... a member of a semi-algebra"?

Comment: @user3911153 semi-ring is also used.